# Problem opening Gedit Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: gedit

I have this problem while trying to open Gedit in Ubuntu 13.10:

```
gedit: symbol lookup error: gedit: undefined symbol: g_option_context_parse_strv
```

I reinstalled Ubuntu, and afterwards I got this issue. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
sudo apt-get install language-pack-gnome-xx?

Where xx stands for You're language... (us/en/de/nl)

Gedit=Gnome Editor. Try using Kate: (KDE-ditor)

Somewhere it is going wrong.I think You've installed (K)Ubuntu without 
network-services. English/USA is standard, nothing changes:

But if You have a foreign language You have to be alert on that:
Date/time and other symbol issues...

On fail, Linux always startup in English/USA mode. Remark that...
I don't like that at all.

That's why here Gedit AND Kedit is in the Dutch language...

Greetings,

Comment: I proved your command my friend. But I had been installed language-pack-gnome-es. The same issue after.